# How to iterate through a list object inside a class object

Tags: python, list, loops, class, iterable

I'm working on writing a script to play Blackjack and can't resolve a defect I encountered tonight. Basically, I'm trying to iterate through a list object that exists within a class. I can always get it to print the first card (i.e. the Five of Hearts), but not the remaining two in my test case.

**Here's the relevant code:**

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + " of " + self.suit

class Play_Pile:

    def __init__(self,pile_owner):
        self.pile_owner = pile_owner
        self.pile_cards = []
        self.pile_state = "NORM"

    def add_card(self,new_card):
        self.pile_cards.append(new_card)

    #THE FIRST IF STATEMENT AND ITS FOR LOOP ARE DEFECTIVE IN THE CONTEXT OF THE TEST CASE
    def __str__(self):
        if self.pile_owner == "HUMAN":
            for card in self.pile_cards:
                return card.rank + " of " + card.suit + "\n"
        elif self.pile_owner == "COMPY":
            return self.pile_cards[0].rank + " of " + self.pile_cards[0].suit
```

**Here's the Unittest test case:**

```
#module references
import unittest
import blackjack

class PlayPile_Display_Test(unittest.TestCase):
        playpile_instance = blackjack.Play_Pile("HUMAN")

        card_1 = blackjack.Card("Hearts", "Five")
        card_2 = blackjack.Card("Spades", "Five")
        card_3 = blackjack.Card("Spades", "Ace")

        playpile_instance.add_card(card_1)
        playpile_instance.add_card(card_2)
        playpile_instance.add_card(card_3)

        print(playpile_instance)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity = 2)
```

Let me know what I'm missing about lists and how to iterate through them within a class?

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over the list, but immidietly you return the value.
You need to accumulate the string and then return the result.

```
str = ""
for card in self.pile_cards:
    str += card.rank + " of " + card.suit + "\n"
return str
```

Comment: Never use the built-in keywords as variable names..

Answer (score 0):

You need to accumulate the string you build for each card, but also use the `Card.__str__` you defined, instead of writing again the Card representation logic (X of Y)

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.pile_owner == "HUMAN":
        result = ""
        for card in self.pile_cards:
            result += str(card) + "\n"
        return result
    elif self.pile_owner == "COMPY":
        return str(self.pile_cards[0])
```

---

You can do it nicely with a `"\n".join` too

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.pile_owner == "HUMAN":
        return "\n".join(map(str, self.pile_cards))
    elif self.pile_owner == "COMPY":
        return str(self.pile_cards[0])
```